# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, umbraco

I used Umbraco 4.11.6 in my website(web application).My website is worked in localhost(tested from Visual studio 2012 and IIS(v7)) but when I run it from internet space I got an error.
The error was:

### Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Razor' could not be loaded.
>
> **WRN:** Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace:

> > [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's
> >     manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception
> >     from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)]    System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +210
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +242
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +17    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +35
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +122
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +12761078
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +503    System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +142    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +334
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath) +203
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +152
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1151
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12881540
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +159    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +12722601
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

a part of WebConfig:

```
<runtime>
<!-- Old asp.net ajax assembly bindings -->
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: check the assembly redirect in your web.config. you might find some redirect there, that references to a version of System.web.razor that you may have not referenced/installed

Comment: I download System.web.razor.dll version 2 from http://originaldll.com/file/system.web.razor.dll/31004.html and replace it. but I got an error.                                 "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)"

Comment: can't help you there sorry..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Quite a few ways to fix this:

1. Install MVC on the web server (which is not always possible).
2. In visual studio you can set dlls to copy to local on build, see the following article (please note MVC dlls have changed names slightly but it gives you the process)
   http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx
3. Copy the appropriate dlls from your GAC into the bin folder of the umbraco site.
   To do this open "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL" in explorer and you will find all of the dlls installed in the GAC and you can copy the appropriate versions into your project.  This is similar to the above method but bypasses building the project.

In terms of files you will likely need more than just System.Web.Razor.dll however this will work for all of the missing files.

Comment: but I'm not using MVC. I'm using Nancy. And installed via Nuget the following packages: 

      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net45" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
      <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Hosting" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
      <package id="Nancy" version="1.4.3" targetFramework="net45" />
      <package id="Nancy.Viewengines.Razor" version="1.4.3" targetFramework="net45" />
      <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: ... and System.Web.Razor is shown in my references as copy local. It's v4.0.30319.  

I removed the reference, and builds ok, but then no app running (forbidden). Reinstalled NUGET and brings back same referenced version.  

Help!! I have no idea what to do.

Comment: In answer 3 you say: "and copy the apporpriate versions into your project." But that's the question!!!  HOW DO WE KNOW what's the appropriate version?

Comment: Not Worked for me :(

Comment: Copying dlls should always be a last resort. Check out the answer of @Yasel instead.

Answer (score 15):

Reinstall package [Microsoft.AspNet.Razor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Razor/2.0.20710), like ADreNaLiNe-DJ [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37718456/553029). The best way to do this is using `Update-Package` command, because The `Install-Package` command does not provide an option to force a reinstall, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages).

```
PM> Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Razor -reinstall
```

Comment: I've found that using `Update-Package` can take forever on a large solution, as it basically reinstalls every package on every project. Consequently, I usually try `Uninstall-Package Package-Name -Force`, followed by `Install-Package Package-Name`. That usually seems to work for me, and it takes about 30 seconds instead of 30 minutes.

Comment: @KenSmith in this case `Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Razor -reinstall`, will only reinstall this especific package and its dependencies (none) in the specific project, so this should not be a case of excessive execution time. I'm not really a fan of forcing things, in my case trying to uninstall the package, without the option -Force, fails

Answer (score 6):

Non of these solutions helped me : either because i can't install anything on the server either because i prefer not including dlls directly without using Nuget.

The solution i used is to install/reinstall the nuget package named **[Microsoft.AspNet.Razor (Microsoft ASP.Net Razor 2.0.20710)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Razor/2.0.20710)**

Answer (score 4):

1. Delete Nuget clear "Temp" folders.
2. Delete Nuget package from project source and then re-install Nuget Package                        using package manager.
3. Remove bin folder.
4. Clean project & build project.
5. Run project.

Done

Comment: What does #1 mean?  Do you mean: In Nuget - remove all packages? - obviously not - that is step 2. Also: which "temp" folders do I have to clear and how?  Do you mean delete the obj and Debug/Release folders in my build? - obviously not - that is step 3.

Comment: did step 2, 3, and even deleted obj folder, then 4 and 5 - does not work.

Comment: as for step 1 - I deleted the '%TEMP%\nuget' foldercontents, deleted the packages folder in the solution root(step 2), did all other stages and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I did not want to install visual studio and development environment, so I have installed AspNetMVC4Setup.exe in Windows server 2016 machine and it solved the problem. The installer was downloaded from Microsoft website.

[image: Properties of AspNetMVC4Setup.exe file]

Comment: This fixed my issue as well. Was receiving multiple errors with "system.web.<thing> not found" and this fixed it for my project. EVEN IF I had installed Visual Studio 2017 with MVC4 selected. Apparently it doesn't install some windows references. This is where I've downloaded AspNetMVC4Setup from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30683

Answer (score 0):

The answer, at [this link](https://support.episerver.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003220552-Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-System-Web-Razor-or-one-of-its-dependencies-), worked for me:

Open the Package Manager Console
Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console
Change the package source to Microsoft and .Net.
Change the project to the one you are debugging.
Run the following command.
Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Reinstall